# Localizing difficulties with latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, localization, nsstring

In my app there is some code to retrieve a position. The standard display method is as a float. (54.23456) I was able to "convert" it to a format with degrees, minutes an seconds. The characters (N)orth, (S)outh (E)ast and (W)est are also added. See my code:

```
double actLat = [[latitude text]doubleValue];
int latSeconds = actLat * 3600;
int latDegrees = latSeconds / 3600;
latSeconds = abs(latSeconds % 3600);
int latMinutes = latSeconds / 60;
latSeconds %= 60;

char latChar = (latitude > 0) ? 'N' : 'S';

double actLon = [[longitude text]doubleValue];
int lonSeconds = actLon * 3600;
int lonDegrees = lonSeconds / 3600;
lonSeconds = abs(lonSeconds % 3600);
int lonMinutes = lonSeconds / 60;
lonSeconds %= 60;

char lonChar = (longitude > 0) ? 'E' : 'W';


NSString *actPosition = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"Actual: %i° %i' %i\" %c" "   " @"%i° %i' %i\" %c \n", latDegrees, latMinutes, latSeconds, latChar,lonDegrees, lonMinutes, lonSeconds, lonChar];

NSString* tempActPos = NSLocalizedString(actPosition, @"");

_actualPosition.text = tempActPos;
```

Right now I'm trying to localize the NSString *actPosition. Actual -> Huidig (in dutch) then the position and the characters (N)oord, Z(uid), (O)ost, (W)est.

I'm completely stuck here. Reading up for several days now on localization but for now I'm unable to understand it apparently. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my code. I added separate localizable strings for the words Actual (NSLocalizedString (@"WordWatched",@"") and added this newly created string in a NSString object to show on my view.

Here is a piece of sample code:

```
NSString *lonStringLocal = NSLocalizedString((valueLon > 0) ? @"East" : @"West", @"");

tempPos = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:valueLat longitude:valueLon];

NSString *watchedPosWord = NSLocalizedString (@"WordWatched", @"");
NSString *recPosition = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@ %i° %i' %i\" %@" "   " @"%i° %i' %i\" %@ \n", watchedPosWord, latDegrees, latMinutes, latSeconds, latStringLocal,lonDegrees, lonMinutes, lonSeconds, lonStringLocal];
```